# NGINX change config location

Tags: nginx

I'm working on getting NGINX configured on a server and I've been able to get all of my files into `/usr/local/nginx/html/`. I've also created an `nginx.conf` file in `/usr/local/nginx/conf`. All it contains is:

```
server {
    root /usr/local/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.html;
}
```

I've been using `/usr/local/` because that's the only thing I have permissions to write in. When I go to look at the site, I still get the Nginx `index.html` page with the message:

> This is the default `index.html` page that is distributed with nginx on EPEL. It is located in `/usr/share/nginx/html`.
>
> You should now put your content in a location of your choice and edit the root configuration directive in the nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

I guess my question is, how can I configure my `nginx.conf` file correctly so that it uses that conf file and pulls from the correction location for the site files?

Comment: Check `/etc/sysconfig/nginx` file, on some environments this file is checked on the init script, and it's a good place to alter the NGINX_CONF_FILE path used in this init script.

Comment: I don't have permissions to edit that file, just the ones specified above. Trying to accomplish this without needing to add new permissions. Thanks!

Comment: The question does not indicate he's using init, but perhaps that's a fair assumption. @heatherthedev, how are you starting nginx?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Whether you're starting nginx in a shell or using a daemon service (which is simply a wrapper around the command line api), the answer lies in [the command line API](http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine).

As you learned, the default location nginx looks in for the configuration file is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, but you can pass in an arbitrary path with the `-c` flag. E.g.:

> ```
> $ nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf
> ```

A couple other notes:

- I doubt there's any good reason to repeat "index.html" in your server block.
- I would name your configuration file "nginx.conf" (you currently indicate that it's just named "conf"). It's the standard.
- Familiarize yourself with another command line flag `-t`, which just checks to make sure your configuration file works. Run `nginx -t` every time after modifying your configuration file and it will spit out any syntax errors. To reload the configuration after changes, use `nginx -s reload`.

Comment: Awesome - currently lacking permissions to actually test this but I'll try it soon.

Comment: Worked great! Now onto solving everything else ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is how to compile nginx to look for the default conf in another directory:

```
./configure --conf-path=/etc/some/other/nginx.conf
make
make install
nginx
```

From the docs:

> --conf-path=path — sets the name of an nginx.conf configuration file. If needs be, nginx can always be started with a different
>   configuration file, by specifying it in the command-line parameter -c
>   file. By default the file is named prefix/conf/nginx.conf.